# Galaxy Note doesn't play sound with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, galaxy

I wrote a very simple android app to test MediaPlayer in Android. App works well on some android phones but this app doesn't work on Galaxy Note.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

protected class SoundPlayer extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.mediaplayertest/" + params[0]);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MPT", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}   

public void startPlayingSound(View v) {
    soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
    try {
        soundPlayer.execute(R.raw.alarm);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("MPT", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void stopPlayingSound(View v) {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Do you know the reason? Do you have any Idea? Is this a bug in Galaxy Note or I missed something?

Comment: did you che device volume level?

Comment: Yes. Device is not silent and volume level is Maximum.

Comment: Anything audio related in the logcat?

Comment: No Exception. No Playing! I got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Proble: MediaPlayer does not play a WAV sound file in Galaxy Note. I've tested the app on Galaxy Gio, S and sony Xperia and everything was ok.

Based on this [link](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988):

The typical errors are as follows:
1. File path is in error. Incorrect directory or Url or Uri found.
2. Media file is in error, incompatible format.
3. Missing permissions.

Finally I found that media format was incorrect. Changing media file and "Note" played the sound!